# How to select data from MySQL then append it into new struct and convert it into byte

Tags: mysql, go

I want to read data from a MySQL database using Go Language. The script is like this

```
func GetAllCountry() []*Country{

    dbConnection := db.ConnectMySQL()

    rows, err := dbConnection.Query("SELECT id, country_code, country_name, phone_code, icon FROM country;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    country := new(Country)
    var countries []*Country
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&country.id, &country.country_code, &country.country_name, &country.phone_code, &country.icon)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        countries = append(countries, country)
        fmt.Println(country)
    }
    return countries
}
```

Data that returned will save into object Struct. The struct is like this

```
type Country struct {
    id              int `json:"Country.id"`
    country_code    string `json:"Country.country_code"`
    country_name    string `json:"Country.country_name"`
    phone_code      string `json:"Country.phone_code"`
    icon            string `json:"Country.icon"`
}
```

In the oher files, I am creating a function to get all data. I call that function, then convert it into `[]byte` because it used to send it into MessageBroker.

Here is the function to convert it into `[]byte`

```
func GetCountry(msg string) []byte {

    // country := new(countryModel.Country)
    var countries []*countryModel.Country

    countries = countryModel.GetAllCountry()
    log.Println("Show result: ", countries)

    jsResult, err := json.Marshal(countries)

    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err, "Failed on GetCountry")
    }


    log.Println("Show result JSON: ", jsResult)

    return jsResult
}
```

But the returned result at `GetCountry` function is not what I want.
In that function, I get

```
[
  {},
  {}
]
```

I show  the data on my console.

```
&{1 ID Indonesia +62 no-data}
&{2 MY Malaysia +60 no-data}
2017/03/20 17:55:27 Show result:  [0xc8200ba410 0xc8200ba410]
2017/03/20 17:55:27 Show result JSON:  [91 123 125 44 123 125 93]
```

Please help.

Comment: Country struct fields should be start with capital letter
`type Country struct { ID  int }`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @M-AbdelRahman in the comment, your `Country` struct fields need to be **exported** (those that start with an uppercase letter) because `json.Marshal` skips over fields that are **unexported** (those that start with a lowercase letter) and that's why you're getting back `{}`.

```
type Country struct {
    Id             int `json:"Country.id"`
    CountryCode    string `json:"Country.country_code"`
    CountryName    string `json:"Country.country_name"`
    PhoneCode      string `json:"Country.phone_code"`
    Icon           string `json:"Country.icon"`
}
```

Your scan will have to change accordingly.

```
err := rows.Scan(&country.Id, &country.CountryCode, &country.CountryName, &country.PhoneCode, &country.Icon)
```